# How To mask personal identification information using any language like java?

Tags: java, encryption, privacy, data-masking

I want to mask PII(personal Identification Information) like Name. Birth Date, SSN, Credit card Number, Phone Number, etc. It should remain same formate , means it looks like real data. And shouldn't be reversible.And it should take less time to mask. Any one please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why aren't your results meeting your requirements? What problems have you had and how do your actual results differ from your expected results?

Comment: Also; replacing the data with random combinations of letters and numbers seems to meet your stated requirements.

Comment: Actually i want make a Data masking algorithm. And it should not be reversible. So.

Comment: So take a SHA hash of the data.

Comment: Compute CRC32 of data; use it as random seed to generate string of bytes equal to length of data, XOR them with data.

Comment: And format should be remain same. Means name Brijesh should be masked with Jayesh, same look and same character. means it is not necessary that the masked value should  be meaningful but  look like original.

Comment: What you are asking for is *way* outside the scope of encryption. Perhaps a linguistic/morphological analyzer (like SEN or something) to analyze words, then you can randomly pick similar morphemes to make the outputs "sound" like the inputs. You will not be able to do what you want in a quick amount of time; although maybe you could approximate by randomly replacing consonants with other consonants and vowels with other vowels or something.

Comment: Actually i am implementing this algorithm into middle-ware and this middle-ware masked data real time. So, main perimeter i concerned are Time, Cost and Privacy. Publisher publish the data and data goes through middle-ware and mask the data and then supply to subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing consonants with consonants, vowels with vowels, and digits with digits:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Example {

    static char randomChar (Random r, String cs, boolean uppercase) {
        char c = cs.charAt(r.nextInt(cs.length()));
        return uppercase ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c;
    }

    static String mask (String str, int seed) {

        final String cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";
        final String vowel = "aeiouy";
        final String digit = "0123456789";

        Random r = new Random(seed);
        char data[] = str.toCharArray();

        for (int n = 0; n < data.length; ++ n) {
            char ln = Character.toLowerCase(data[n]);
            if (cons.indexOf(ln) >= 0)
                data[n] = randomChar(r, cons, ln != data[n]);
            else if (vowel.indexOf(ln) >= 0)
                data[n] = randomChar(r, vowel, ln != data[n]);
            else if (digit.indexOf(ln) >= 0)
                data[n] = randomChar(r, digit, ln != data[n]);
        }

        return new String(data);

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println(mask("John Doe, 534 West Street, Wherever, XY. (888) 535-3593. 399-35-3535", 0));

    }
}
```

That produces the output:

```
    Bumk Tyy, 194 Wyrd Tggoyb, Flikibod, QY. (557) 722-5385. 055-08-1462
```

From the input:

```
    John Doe, 534 West Street, Wherever, XY. (888) 535-3593. 399-35-3535
```

It's up to you to generate the seed. Use a seed based on the input data (e.g. a checksum) as well as a consistent RNG if you want to guarantee that the same input always produces the same output.

A performance optimization could be made by using a character class table instead of e.g. `vowel.indexOf()`. Further micro-optimizations could be made (e.g. re-using `Random`, operating only on `char[]` and reducing new `String` allocations, etc.)

Heavy difficulties will be encountered with full Unicode support. Masking also does not change length of components.

Over all I would rate this a poor, but at least moderately interesting, algorithm.

I don't think you understand that what you are asking for (output that *looks* real) is outside the scope of normal encryption topics and doesn't lend itself well to "efficiency", as some amount of morphological analysis would be required to produce meaningful results (and again, internationalization complicates this significantly).

Comment: Thank You Jason. This give me a good direction for my Algorithm.